# How to get route params to work with vue-router and vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I'm trying to pass data from a component to $route.params.post but somewhere along the line it's failing and I'm not sure how to get it to work.

In my component I'm using `router-link` to go to a specific path in my routes file but it's not routing to the specified component.

```
// Component.vue

<router-link :to="{ path: 'replies', params: { post: postId }}">
    <div class="button is-light is-small has-replies" @click=" postId = thread.no ">Replies</div> 
    //clicking replies will push the thread number to data and load it into the params
</router-link>

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            postId: null
        }
    }
}

// ./routes/index.js

import Replies from '../components/Replies'

routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Frontpage },
    { path: '/replies/:post', component: Replies }
]
```

Clicking the button should open the Replies component with the route looking like `/replies/#` but it's just loading a blank page and ignoring the component entirely. I'm importing `vuex-router-sync` on my `main.js`, but I can't tell if that's the issue, but I'm aware it very well may be since I'm not entirely sure I'm using `vuex-router-sync` correctly.

Comment: Why don't you set the thread.no to the router-link directly? Why this strange detour of setting it to the data first?

Comment: After applying saurabh's solution and setting up the link correctly I'm linking directly to `thread.no` through `router-link`. When it wasn't working I guess I was just trying out different ways to make it work not realizing it was a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like following, as `postId` is not a URL parameter, but part of the URL itself:

```
<router-link :to="'replies/'+ postId'">
    <div class="button is-light is-small has-replies" @click=" postId = thread.no ">Replies</div> 
    //clicking replies will push the thread number to data and load it into the params
</router-link>
```